# mqtt client not connected and connection in progress error

Tags: android, mqtt

I m Connecting to mqtt server in android sticky service to publish and subscribe to topics.i want to publish and subscribe even when app is closed.This works but only for very few minutes then connection to client is lost I get client not connected error  and on reconnection (calling connection method again  )I get connect already in progress (32110) error ,sometimes it connects with out error . Everything works fine only for first few minutes.How to keep mqtt client always connected in  sticky service

Comment: Do you have automatic reconnect enabled?

Comment: Yes but doesn't work. mqttConnectOptions.setAutomaticReconnect(true);so I do it again

Comment: What version of Android are you using on, and what locks have you taken to keep the process running and the network stack active?

Comment: I m running on Android N ,I m using sticky service  to keep the mqtt service running in background.i connect to steady wifi I face the issue after few minutes of connection ,I hv not tested when network changes or is disconnected

Comment: there is a suspiciously similar issue in paho, maybe android uses paho